# How to get failed records while insertion in a CSV

Tags: talend

I am inserting records from CSV to salesforce using talend tool. I want failed records in a separate CSV. Please provide me some solution?
Thanks!!!

Comment: can you validate answer if its correct?

Answer (score 1):

- Deactivate tSalesforceOutput / Advanced Settings / Extended Output (might result in slower performance)
- Add another row with right click, Row / Rejects
- Use this row in a csv component

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Create another tFileoutputdelimited

Go in tmap after create a new output in tmap

Go in the option in new output and put "catch output reject" to true.

Join the new output to the tfileoutputdelimited